# Apache Camel: How to read files in sorted format based on modified time(files are dumped in milliseconds delay)

Tags: java, apache-camel, endpoint

I am using EIH 4.1 version and have written below EndPoint in my route to process the files dumped with milliseconds delay but it is failing when the files are being dumped in 100 ms delay. I have written java code to copy the files with sleep(100) to "in" folder for processing.

```html
<from id="getB2mmlProcessFromFileSystem" uri="file:{{in.path}}?idempotentRepository=#hcStore&amp;moveFailed=.failed/$simple{file:onlyname}&amp;move={{archive-from-erp.path}}/{{common.fname.pattern}}&amp;maxMessagesPerPoll=1&amp;eagerMaxMessagesPerPoll=false&amp;readLock=changed&amp;readLockMinAge=100s&amp;readLockCheckInterval=1000&amp;sortBy=reverse:file:modified/>
```

I have tried below end point to process the file based on modified time.

```html
<from id="getB2mmlProcessFromFileSystem" uri="file:{{in.path}}?idempotentRepository=#hcStore&amp;moveFailed=.failed/$simple{file:onlyname}&amp;move={{archive-from-erp.path}}/{{common.fname.pattern}}&amp;maxMessagesPerPoll=1&amp;eagerMaxMessagesPerPoll=false&amp;readLock=changed&amp;readLockMinAge=100s&amp;readLockCheckInterval=1000&amp;sortBy=reverse:file:modified/>
```

The above end point is working fine when the delay between files are 500 ms but failing when it is 400 and below.

I have written below java code to copy the files to "in" folder with 100ms delay but the files are picked by Camel is in random and not based on modified time.

```java
public class Testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException { 
        Path sourceDirectory = Paths.get("C:/Users/autorock/Desktop/Source/productionSchedule_2023-08-19_productionLine_9570770741.xml", args); 
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            String filePath="productionLine_9570757741_"+i;
            Path targetDirectory = Paths.get("C:/temp/eihub/in/"+filePath); 
            Files.copy(sourceDirectory, targetDirectory); 
            Thread.sleep(100);
            System.out.println("file copied");
        }
    } 
}
```